# Fuzzy filename search with `projectile-find-file` no more?

Tags: projectile

In order to perform a fuzzy search over file names in a project, I used `projectile-find-file` in the past. For example typing in 'a' would interactively restrict the search to all the files that start with 'a' in all subdirectories.

In recent versions `projectile-find-file` behaves differently, it asks for a full file name with `[project] Find file:` and does not perform a fuzzy search over all files in the subdirectories. It is also possible that some configuration change changed this behavior in my setup, however I don't see an obvious culprit.

How can I get the old `projectile-find-file` behavior back?

Comment: The behavior you desire with `projectile-find-file` works for me with the latest version of `projectile`. Do you have other frameworks like `ivy`, `vertico`, or `orderless` and related settings that you may have changed in between?

Comment: Based on @SwarnenduBiswas's comment, it sounds like you should try to provide a reproducible recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). IOW, remove anything extraneous. If you don't see the problem when you use `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Yes, enabling `ido`, `ivy` or `helm` modes fixed the issue. When none of these modes are enabled, calling `projectile-find-file` doesn't appear to result in fuzzy file name searching.